# Python regex get pairs of floats from string if present

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have some strings which contain a pairs of frequencies or pairs of frequency ranges

My regex function gets the following list from that example string:

```
example_string = ':2.400-2.483ghz;5.725-5.850ghz&#x0d;&#x0d;transmissionpower(eirp),2'
re.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+.hz)", example_string)
# example output: ['2.483ghz', '5.850ghz']
```

How can I extract the range of frequencies rather than just the single float after the `-` character?

Output should be `['2.400-2.483ghz', '5.725-5.850ghz']`

Comment: Do you have any guarantees about the line format?  Will the ; always be present?  Are the units always in GHz?  Are there always two ranges per line?  Any more details you can give will help you get the most generic answer that will work in most or all cases.

Comment: Units will either be MHz or GHz, and the : won't always be present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should (mostly) work to find all the occurences of those strings in the code (it should handle any number of ranges in the line):

```
>>> example_string = ':2.400-2.483ghz;5.725-5.850ghz&#x0d;&#x0d;transmissionpower(eirp),2'
>>> re.findall('([0-9.]+-[0-9.]+.?hz)', example_string)
['2.400-2.483ghz', '5.725-5.850ghz']
```

To break it down:

- `[0-9.]+` - will find 1 or more numbers and .s together (e.g. 2.400)
- `.?hz` finds 0 or 1 characters followed by 'hz' so it should handle most units (e.g. hz, ghz, etc.)

The whole thing essentially looks for `<number><dash><number><units>` zero or more times per line.

It's worth pointing out that, like most regexes, this is still pretty brittle so if the string is malformatted, if it's GHz instead of ghz, if the numbers are in scientific notation, etc., it will break, but hopefully you can adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to make it work for just single frequencies?

Comment: @kynnem `r'((?:[0-9.]+-)?[0-9.]+.?hz)'`

Comment: @kynnem What do you mean by single frequencies?  A single range like `2.400-2.483ghz` or a single value like `2.483ghz`?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex:

```sh
(?:\d+\.\d+-)?\d+\.\d+.hz
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJ3zBA/2)

**Code:**

```sh
>>> import re
>>> s = ':2.400-2.483ghz;5.725-5.850ghz&#x0d;&#x0d;transmissionpower(eirp),2'
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\d+\.\d+-)?\d+\.\d+.hz', s);
['2.400-2.483ghz', '5.725-5.850ghz']
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?:\d+\.\d+-)?`: In an **optional group** match a floating point number followed by hyphen
- `\d+\.\d+`: Match a floating point number
- `.hz`: Match any character followed by `hz`